# Swift: How to loop through all characters in a string, and also determine what characters belongs to a specific subset

Tags: python, swift

This Python code loops through all characters in a string and prints out characters that belong to a specific subset.

```
str = "abcdefg12345"
for ch in str:
    if ch in "ab34":
        print( ch )
```

How can I translate that code into Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `Set` to hold the characters you are searching for, and then use `contains` to test for inclusion:

```
let str = "abcdefg12345"
let searchSet = Set("ab34")
for ch in str {
    if searchSet.contains(ch) {
       println(ch)
    }
}
```

Comment: If order doesn't matter, this can be simplified a little further. `for char in Set("abcdefg12345").intersect("ab34") { println(char) }`